# SChannel send intermediate certificate chain from memory store

Tags: ssl, schannel

I am working with a server using SChannel TLS.  I use SCHANNEL_CRED and AcquireSecurityCredentials to create the security credentials that are then passed to AcceptSecurityContext.  Everything seems to work ok, but SChannel will not send an intermediate certificate for the end certificate if it is not in the system or user certificate store.  I'd like it to send the certificate from a memory store but this does not seem to be working.  Is there a way to specify a temporary intermediate certificate without adding it to a permanent store?